# Taking average of nested vectors of doubles in Struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column that is an array of struct in a Spark DataFrame like

```
|-- sTest: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- embed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

that has a variable number of nested arrays ("embed") that all have equal length.

For each row, I want to take the average of these embeddings and assign the result as a column to a new dataframe (the existing + the new column).

I have read of some people using `explode` but this is not quite what I want. I ultimately wanted to do an aggregate for each row computing the average embedding (`array(float)`).

A minimal example of a dataframe with ArrayType(StructType) column:

```
val structureData = Seq(
  Row(Seq(Row("value1 ", Seq(1, 2, 3)), Row("value1 ", Seq(4, 5, 6)))),
  Row(Seq(Row("value2", Seq(4,5,6))), Row("value1 ", Seq(1, 1, 1)))
)

val structureSchema = new StructType()
  .add("sTest", ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("value", StringType)
    .add("embed", ArrayType(IntegerType))))
```

The desired output would be

```
Row(2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
Row(2.5, 3, 3.5)
```

Comment: can you add some input data and expected output too ?

Comment: I have updated with a simple example dataframe and output.

Comment: Does your desired output line up to your example data? I don't seem to understand what you're trying to do. If you want the average of each embed array wouldn't you get:
`Row(2, 5), Row(5, 1)` ?

Comment: @KitMenke I mean to take the average of the vectors in the sense of an “average pooling” operation. So row1 has two vectors `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`, so I would add these vectors yielding `[5, 7, 9]` and then divide by the number of arrays, 2, to get `[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]`. Does this make sense? I actually flubbed the second example output row - I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data essentially look like a matrix, and you are trying to summarize the matrix by column, so it's natural to consider using the `Summarizer` from the `org.apache.spark.ml.stat` package.

Input data:

```scala
case class sTest(value: String, embed: Seq[Int])

val df = Seq(
  Tuple1(Seq(
    sTest("value1", Seq(1, 2, 3)), 
    sTest("value2", Seq(4, 5, 6))
  )),
  Tuple1(Seq(
    sTest("value3", Seq(4, 5, 6)), 
    sTest("value4", Seq(1, 1, 1))
  ))
) toDF("nested")
```

Calculate the average:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Summarizer

val array2vecUdf = udf((array: Seq[Int]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray.map(_.toDouble))
})

val vec2arrayUdf = udf((vec: Vector) => {
  vec.toArray
})

val stage1 = df
  // Create a rowid so we can explode, extract the embed field as a vector and collect.
  .withColumn("rowid", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withColumn("exp", explode($"nested"))
  .withColumn("embed", $"exp".getItem("embed"))
  .withColumn("embed_vec", array2vecUdf($"embed"))

val avg = Summarizer.metrics("mean").summary($"embed_vec")

val stage2 = stage1
  .groupBy("rowid")
  .agg(avg.alias("avg_vec"))
  // Convert back from vector to array.
  .select(vec2arrayUdf($"avg_vec.mean").alias("avgs"))

stage2.show(false)
```

Result:

```
+---------------+
|avgs           |
+---------------+
|[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]|
|[2.5, 3.0, 3.5]|
+---------------+
```

Comment: Could you perhaps assist in how I would assign (or join) these averaged vectors back to the original dataframe - where `value1` has `[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]` and `value2` has `[2.5, 3.0, 3.5]`?

Apologies as this may be better suited as a seperate question.

Comment: In the last step (.select(...alias("avgs"))), also select the "rowid", then join back with stage1.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you :)